# python pygtk code runned under terminal and no screen show up

Tags: python, terminal, pygtk

I have searched and could not find any solution ; sorry for this newbie question and if I wrote it in wrong place.

I have written this simple code to run python and try to run in terminal but I have seen nothing show up. by the way in terminal screen nothing happens;it seems program is running but there should be a window popup but nothing. what am I missing ?

```
import sys
sys.path.append("\\usr\lib\python2.7\dist-packages")
import gtk
class PyApp(gtk.Window):
    def _init_(self):
            super(PyApp.self)._init_()
            self.set_default_size(640,480)
            self.set_title("PyGTK")
            self.show_all()

PyApp()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: `__init__` should have _two_ underscores (four in total).

Comment: now getting error :  `super(PyApp.self).__init__()
AttributeError: type object 'PyApp' has no attribute 'self'`

Comment: maybe I had to read this gtk tutorial again ; I might be missing something but __int__ seems worked at least I am getting reaction

Comment: You need more attention to detail... That should be `super(PyApp, self)` with a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("\\usr\lib\python2.7\dist-packages")
import gtk
class PyApp(gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
            gtk.Window.__init__(self)
            self.set_default_size(640,480)
            self.set_title("PyGTK")
            self.show_all()

PyApp()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: @melic please accept my solution if it solved your problem.